# Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18407cb5c)

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code

I keep on getting this error:

> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x18407cb5c)

whenever I run this code:

```
import UIKit
import SQLite

class TakeMoney: UIViewController {
    //for json
    let json = "[{"+"\"UserID\":\""+"\(Int(stored_ID) ?? -1)\""+",\"Name\":"+"\"\(stored_name)\""+"}]"
    //
    var img : UIImage? = nil

    //variable for image display space
    @IBOutlet weak var ImageDisplay: UIImageView!
    //variable for raw qr image output
    var qrCodeImage : CIImage!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(json)
        ////takes out the input and encodes it
        ///runs on main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            let data = self.json.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: false)
            let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator") //defining filter
            filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage") //utilising filter
            filter?.setValue("L", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel") //defining the level of quality, H is highest, L is lowest
            self.qrCodeImage = filter?.outputImage //getting the filter to output raw image
            //to set the size of qr code
            let length = self.ImageDisplay.frame.size.width
            let height = self.ImageDisplay.frame.size.height
            let transformedImage = self.qrCodeImage.transformed(by: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: length, y: height))
            //
            self.img = UIImage(ciImage: transformedImage)
            print(self.img!)
            if(self.img == nil){
                print("It is empty")
            }
            else{
                self.ImageDisplay.image = self.img
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is supposed to take the JSON value and convert it into a QR code which would then be shown through the 'ImageDisplay' image view element. It works when I run it on a simulator, but when I run it on my phone, it doesn't work and always crashes producing the earlier stated error.

It crashes at the point where it has to assign the UIImage to the image view, on the line:

```
self.ImageDisplay.image = self.img
```

Comment: It would be best if you told us which line exactly is causing the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy oh yea....forgot to add that...editing it right now

Comment: @JonathanLamptey Post an answer if you ever solved this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, `self.ImageDisplay` is nil. Since it is an implicitly unwrapped optional, accessing it will crash if it's nil.

You'll need to make sure that it is connected in your storyboard/xib.

Comment: This can't be the issue. A few lines before the line causing the crash, the frame of `ImageDisplay` is referenced. And there would be a different exception (typically EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION).

Comment: Yea that is not the issue as it is already connected to the storyboard. I checked

Answer (score -1):

You are force unwrapping a value before actually checking if is nil in `print(self.img!)`.

It is likely that the force unwrap is returning nil and thus, crashing the app.

Comment: That didn't work, it still crashes at `self.ImageDisplay.image = self.img`